# How to include a php file for two different views in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have the following good working code for my Joomla site which is loading a php file for a certain view:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$view = $jinput->get('view');
if($view == 'pluginresponse'){
    include ("templates/default/datalayer.php");
    }
```

I would like to include this php file for a second view also. I have tried with the following code but unfortunately lack the knowledge in php so it is not working as expected:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$view = $jinput->get('view');
$layout = $jinput->get('layout');
if(($view == 'pluginresponse') or ($view == 'cart' && $layout == 'order_done'){
    include ("templates/default/datalayer.php");
    }
```

Could I please get assistance or some info how to code this correctly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be missing a ")"
modify

```
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$view = $jinput->get('view');
$layout = $jinput->get('layout');
if(($view == 'pluginresponse') or ($view == 'cart' && $layout == 'order_done'){
    include ("templates/default/datalayer.php");
    }
```

to this

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$view = $jinput->get('view');
$layout = $jinput->get('layout');
if(  ($view == 'pluginresponse') or 
     ($view == 'cart' && $layout == 'order_done') ){
    include ("templates/default/datalayer.php");
    }
```

other than that I do not have a joomla install to test this with  hope this helps

Comment: I tried further and the code works. Thank you. Unfortunately not perfectly since the order_done page needs for some reason to be reloaded so the code can work. Then the code is taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I got so far which is working perfectly for my needs it the following. As said it is maybe not the nicest solution but works.

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$view = $jinput->get('view');
if(($view == 'pluginresponse') or (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "cart/order_done") !== false) ){
    include ("templates/default/datalayer.php");
    }
```